# Parse Android Query Not Working

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to fetch data from a Parse Class test, but I could'nt get anything back with the following code. Please help! thanks!

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Test");

        try {
            items = query.find();
            Log.d("count", query.count() + " items");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing Android and JavaScript syntax here.  The basic example is:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Docs here: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries

Comment: Cool..   Go ahead and click the checkmark to mark this as an accepted answer.  Welcome to StackOverflow.